# Omit decimal value

Tags: python, numpy

```
TestVal_For_Prediction = TestVal_For_Prediction.reset_index(drop=True)
Prediction = TestVal_For_Prediction.iloc[:,[0,2,3]]
Prediction["Adj_Marketing_Expenses"] = TestVal_For_Prediction["Marketing_Expenses_x"] + TestVal_For_Prediction["Marketing_Expenses_y"]
Prediction.rename(columns={'Marketing_Expenses_y': 'Marketing_Expenses_Range'},inplace=True)
Prediction.rename(columns={'Marketing_Expenses_x': 'Budgeted_Marketing_Expenses'},inplace=True)

Y_pred1 = regressor.predict(Prediction["Adj_Marketing_Expenses"].values.reshape(-1,1))

Prediction['Predicted_Sales'] = Y_pred1
Prediction.round({"Predicted_Sales":1})
Prediction
```

Output:

[image: Screen Shot]

The "Predicted_Sales" Value is like xxx.0 end with point zero (decimal). How can I omit the decimal and convert it into an integer value?

Comment: Do you want to actually *convert* the pandas column from float to integer, or just *print it as an integer*? Either way, this has existing duplicates both on SO and in the pandas doc,  please read them.

Comment: Also, 'Omit decimal value' is a very unclear title, it doesn't say what object and datatype we're dealing with; yours is a dataframe with a float value, which came from a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pandas then you can use astype().
Prediction['Predicted_Sales'] = Prediction['Predicted_Sales'].astype("int")
This will convert your entire column to int

Comment: The data appears to be in a array, not stored as a single value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Can you show me the final script please ? Still new in python :)

Comment: this is using my data.. hope you understand..>>> df["latitude"]
0    17.234567
1    17.322340
2    17.422430
3    17.452340
4    17.542340
Name: latitude, dtype: float64
>>> df["latitude"]  = df["latitude"].astype("int")
>>> df["latitude"]
0    17
1    17
2    17
3    17
4    17
Name: latitude, dtype: int32

Answer (score 0):

If the values are in a numpy array, which they appear to be, then convert it to  an int as so:
`Y_pred1 = regressor.predict(Prediction["Adj_Marketing_Expenses"].values.reshape(-1,1).astype(int))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I have try your script, but still the same result. when I print the Prediction, Predicted_Values still in decimal format. Do you have any idea ? Appreciate your help

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are blatant duplicates, they'll only get closed anyway so you won't get any rep from that.